# Adding 2 Caml queries in same executeQueryAsync

Tags: javascript, caml-query, caml

Is it possible to use two different queries to get to different lists and use them in the same `executeQueryAsync()`

Something like this :

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="SortOrder"/></OrderBy></View></Query>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

var camlQuery1 = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery1.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="SortOrder"/></OrderBy></View></Query>');
this.collListItem1 = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


clientContext.load(collListItem,collListItem1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, but you will have to load the list item collection seperately like below and call executequery once.

```
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.load(collListItem1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also valid

```
var allWebs = spCtx.LoadQuery(spCtx.Web.Webs.Include(SharePointWeb.WebInclusions));
var allLists = spCtx.LoadQuery(spCtx.Web.Lists.Include(SharePointList.ListInclusions));
spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

where WebInclusions and ListInclusions are lambda expressions that nominate the fields you want to load.